# interpolation before dimensionless?

Tags: filter, signals

Maybe a silly question.

Let's say I have two measurements.

The first measurement, x1, is measured at t = [ 0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
the second is measurement, x2, is measured at time = [2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5]

Now I want to make both measurements dimensionless to time t=7.5.

Assuming our signal is very noise.
Do I simply linearly interpolate measurement x1 from [0:0.5:20] and compare it to t=7.5. Isn't this amplifying noise?

Should I first filter the raw signal and then make it dimensionless in respective to t=7.5?

Comment: Should this be a question on https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?